# Difference between transaction in SQL Server and ADO.NET?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

What is difference between transaction in SQL Server and using transaction in ADO.NET?

Please reply with proper logic. I just want to know in terms of performance.

I just want to know if i am using transaction(Begin End Trans) and using SqlTransaction class in ado.net for similar set of queries then which is better to use ?

Comment: What makes you believe there *is* a difference?

Comment: i just want to know in terms of performance.

Comment: As I'm trying to say: there is **NO** difference - ADO.NET uses the SQL Server transaction system (unless you're talking about `TransactionScope` in .NET - that's a different story)

Comment: There is a similar question been raised : **http://forums.asp.net/t/1739215.aspx/1**

Comment: In this link "Stored Procedure will be pre-compiled and is executed directly, so it's faster than generic ADO.NET's nested (embedded statements)." is given. Is this true ?

Comment: @Saurabh: It is another question to be asked :)

Comment: You can use store procedure in conjunction with Asp.Net Transaction management. As for Transaction management there is no difference i believe.

Comment: I just want to know if i am using transaction(Begin End Trans) in sql server and using SqlTransaction class in ado.net for similar set of queries then which is better to use ?

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference between a ADO.Net transaction and SQL Server transaction, as far as transaction handling. Personally, I prefer initiating transactions at a higher level that ADO.NET offers, because it normally gives me greater flexibility in setting the scope of the transaction.

Comment: In "forums.asp.net/t/1739215.aspx/1" link "Stored Procedure will be pre-compiled and is executed directly, so it's faster than generic ADO.NET's nested (embedded statements)." is given. Is this true ?

Comment: @Saurabh - Your question has to do with the difference between transactions and, I presume, the difference in performance between committing and/or rolling back, the transaction itself, not the various T-SQL statements that comprise the transaction. Based on this, I'm saying there is no difference. Pre-compiled stored procedures are a completely different question.

Comment: I just want to know if i am using transaction(Begin End Trans) in sql serverand using SqlTransaction class in ado.net for similar set of queries then which is better to use ?

Comment: That is a subjective question. Personally, I prefer handling transactions at the C# level. This gives me much greater flexibility in handling the scope of transactions.

Comment: @Saurabh: speed and performance are not different. What I'd recommend doing is choose one style (either transactions in ADO.NET or in SQL Server directly) and then stick with that - don't mix transaction handling...

Comment: @Saurabh - I agree with marc_s. You are placing far too much importance on a trivial performance difference, if there is one. Pick one that suits your requirements. Either way, the performance will be satisfactory. We use ADO.Net transactions in performance critical manufacturing applications and we are perfectly satisfied with the results.

Comment: But In ado.net when we create SqlTransaction object then it hold the memory, we can reduce this by directly writting trans inside sql server. Any thoughts.

Comment: @Saurabh - You don't seem to be listening to what people are telling you. Performance wise, the difference is meaningless. IT DOESN'T MATTER. Pick an approach and go with it.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server level transactions only when I need to update Multiple Tables, like I have a Master Table, and a Detail Table, I want to update both the Master and Detail tables.

ADO.Net (.Net Level) transaction only for one project, it is an SQL 2008 project, there was some requirement like, I need to save some DOC files in Database, it is using a SQL 2008 feature, called FileStream. If enable FileStream it will create some shared folder on the server, and Saves all the file data into this Folder, which can only read by SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

An ADO.net transaction is more convenient if you are making changes to multiple databases within a transaction and want to roll all of them back in case of an error.